# impdp syntax for schema that is not available on other database

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, users, impdp, expdp

My intention is to import the data of schema 'SCOTT'. I have exported it from db1 using expdp scott/tiger schemas=scott dumpfile=scottexp.dmp ...... 
Now When I try to import the same in database db2 what would be the syntax. I don't have the SCOTT user in database db2(intentionally deleted to test). I tried with sysdba & system but unsuccessful.

impdp xxxxx schemas=yyyyy dumpfile=scottexp.dmp....

Please let me know the xxxxx and yyyyy values here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. But I don't want to explicitly create the user and import but the command itself should create the user. I want the same user 'scott'.

Comment: You need to perform the export and imports as a system user. Then it should automatically create the user when importing. You need the permissions when exporting in order to be able to extract the password information etc and when importing in order to be able to create the user.

Answer (score 1):

impdp SCOTT/password directory=DUMPDIR dumpfile=fromuser.dmp logfile=impdp.log remap_schema=SCOTT:DEV_LOCAL FULL=YES

**DEV_LOCAL will be the local empty schema that you should create!**